# tomcat 6 startup exception

Tags: tomcat6

I'm running tomcat6 on centos 6, keeps getting the following error in the log upon startup.  I have a pretty standard out of the box configuration, it's a new install.

```
org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
SEVERE: destroyMBeans: Throwable
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Cannot create object name for org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector@d02b2b6
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createObjectName(MBeanUtils.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.destroyMBean(MBeanUtils.java:1416)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.destroyMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.destroyMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:1005)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.destroyMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:971)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerLifecycleListener.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:643)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:618)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this tomcat6 bug report:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48612

It is a bug in 6.0.24 (current for centos6) and fixed in subsequent versions.  We'll have to wait for the fix to trickle down.

Whether there's a workaround is not specified.  Whether it is actually SEVERE is not specified...  Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you install tomcat6-webapps package the error disappears, probably a missed dependency.